Can I use "prone" in (1), if can't, why?

I'm wondering if I could use the word "prone" in this sentence. If not, is there any reasoning to back it up?

And if this was a test you've done, say what you answered, what the correct answer was, what the test was about, and how your teacher explained it.

I'd use likely, but prone works.
